# Decode iPhone app transaction receipt info into PHP array

Tags: php, iphone, in-app-purchase

> { "signature" = "Alof/CEJ8a=="; "purchase-info" = "ewoJIml0";
>   "environment" = "Test"; "pod" = "100"; "signing-status" = "0"; }

What is the best way with PHP to parse this iPhone in-app purchase transaction post into an array?  Thanks.

Comment: You could replace the ='s with :'s and the ;'s with ,'s and then use json_decode().

Comment: @bozdoz You should answer with that.

Comment: What about [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

Comment: @AlexsanderAkers It's not valid `JSON`, just looks like it wants to be.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is the 'best' way, but it's one way. Since the data string is separated by common characters (each key/value set by a `;`, then an `=` between the key/value), the bulk of the parsing can be done with [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). And you can use [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) - with a custom character list - to remove the extra characters around the whole string, and the keys/values.

Note that this will expects that a key never has a `=` (although a value may):

```
$data = '{ "signature" = "Alof/CEJ8a=="; "purchase-info" = "ewoJIml0"; "environment" = "Test"; "pod" = "100"; "signing-status" = "0"; }';

//remove the braces, spaces, and trailing semicolon
$data = trim($data, '{}; ');

$array = array();

//split on ';'
foreach(explode(';', $data) as $set){
  //parse key/value
  list($key, $value) = explode('=', $set, 2);
  $array[trim($key, '"\' ')] = trim($value, '"\' ');
}

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
  [signature] => Alof/CEJ8a==
  [purchase-info] => ewoJIml0
  [environment] => Test
  [pod] => 100
  [signing-status] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the ='s with :'s and the ;'s with ,'s and then use json_decode().

Like so:

```
$data = '{ "signature" = "Alof/CEJ8a=="; "purchase-info" = "ewoJIml0"; "environment" = "Test"; "pod" = "100"; "signing-status" = "0"; }';
$data = explode('" =',$data);
$data = implode('" :',$data);
$data = explode(';',$data);
array_pop($data);
$data = implode(',',$data);
$data = explode(' ',$data);
$data = implode('',$data);
$data .= "}";
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

Check it out [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Vz6Le3).

Comment: What about a replace of `";` with `,` and `" = "` with `:`. Wouldn't that convert it to `JSON` without the `explode`/`implode`? `preg_replace` could be used in the case that the whitespace may vary.

Comment: For me it's less about performance, and more about the next guy that has to look at the code. A replace would seem to be clearer (at least to me).

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = '{ "signature" = "Alof/CEJ8a=="; "purchase-info" = "ewoJIml0"; "environment" = "Test"; "pod" = "100"; "signing-status" = "0"; }';
$search = array('/\s\=\s/', '/;\s\}$/', '/;/');
$replace = array(':', '}', ',');
$json = preg_replace($search, $replace, $data);

print_r(json_decode($json));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [signature] => Alof/CEJ8a==
    [purchase-info] => ewoJIml0
    [environment] => Test
    [pod] => 100
    [signing-status] => 0
)
```